# How can I change the tensor shape from 4 dim to 5 dim in Keras?

Tags: keras, reshape, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

now, I have 70 images with 200x200x1(one channel only).
I converted the shape of this training date set from (70,200,200,1) to (1,70,200,200,1) before operating model.fit.(actually my code is RNN)

So my RNN model starts as below.

```python
def get_RNN
input1 = Input((img_rows, img_cols, 1), name='input1') # (?,200,200,1)

conv1 = ConvLSTM2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input1)
```

In the first line, a error created like below.

```python
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv_lst_m2d_1: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4
```

I think I have to edit my first line of get_RNN.
Is there anyone to know how to change this line?
I want to make a shape of (1,?,200,200,1), where ? is 70.

Comment: It is not clear whether 70 is the number of samples that you have or the number of timesteps per sample ? To understand how you can modify your code, please refer to the section dedicated to ConvLSTM2D at this page: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/.

Comment: I want to apply crnn to medical image segmentation. so my data consists 70 slices as size of 200x200 and one channel for one patient. hence, I think the sample size is 1 and time is 70. Is this right?

Comment: Yes that could make sense. Have you tried this ? `input1 = Input(shape = (70, img_rows, img_cols, 1), name='input1')` (based on the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

I have another problem.

I made input data and output data as a nparray type before perform model.fit function.

imgs_input.shape is (1, 70, 200, 200, 1)
imgs_output.shape is (1, 70, 200, 200, 1)

after that, I performed model.fit as below code.

```
hist = model.fit(imgs_input, imgs_output, batch_size=16, epochs=30, verbose=2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

and than, my RNN network ran..

```
def get_RNN
input1 = Input((None, img_rows, img_cols, 1), name='input1') # (?,?,200,200,1)
conv1 = ConvLSTM2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', return_sequences=True)(input1)
```

If my code was correct,
a shape of input1 will be (1, 70, 200, 200, 1).
But I always got the shape of (70, 1, 200, 200, 1).

how I can make batch size=1 instead of 70?

Comment: What about `input1 = Input(batch_shape=(None, 70, img_rows, img_cols, 1), name='input1') ` ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it still allocated as a shape of (70,1,200,200,1) after conv1 layer. I think input layer was correct, however, convlstm2d layer did not realize correctly both batch size and sequence size. Do I need preprocessing for input data in RNN?